# Как перенести Windows 11 на новый ssd?

Tags: windows, поиск-программ, windows-11

Windows 11 установлена на m2 nvme ssd, загрузка uefi.

Купил новый ssd большего размера и хочу перенести систему (с сохранением установленных порграмм, настроек и всего остального) на него. Как это сделать? Есть идее про копирование образа раздела или всего диска, ноне уверен, что винда к такому нормально отнесётся.

Есть возможность установить оба ссд одновременно. Оба от Samsung.

Comment: Про 11 не возьмусь утверждать, 10 свободно переносится клонированием. можно попробовать почистить ОС от настроек железа, но не уверен что это то что вам нужно(используется для создания "образов" дисков с предустановленным софтом но на разное железо)... https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview?view=windows-11  https://petri.com/using-sysprep-in-windows-11/

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, я внезапно обнаружил, что у самсунга есть своя утилита для миграции, но ещё не попробовал. А очистка вроде не нужна - ничего не меняется кроме ссд.

Comment: Очистка может быть нужна чтобы удалить ключи железа, если ОС завязывается на ssd(uefi) :) а если этого нет - то и утилит не нужно особо, просто клонирование раздела сработает :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, она уже на uefi.

Comment: CloneZilla LiveCD в режиме `disk-to-disk` не?

Comment: @donRumata, а сработает? И что там с зашифрованным разделом?

Comment: Т.к. клонзилла работает на уровне разделов - ей похрен чё там внутри.

Comment: @donRumata, ей-то пофиг, а винда загрузиться сможет?

Comment: Ну блин, я ж говорю, работа с блочным уровнем. Все ACL NTFS и 256 символов на путь на этом уровне абстракции не затрагиваются.

Comment: @donRumata, при чём тут ntfs? Я про разделы диска говорю: шифрованный на 100 метров, основной с виндой и какой-то раздел восстановления на 616 метров. Глянь скриншот в ответе. Я же правильно понимаю, что ты предлагал весь диск копировать, а не раздел винды? Я как-то должен сделать вывод, что при копировании шифрованного раздела загрузка вообще будет возможна? Там внутри нет какого-нибудь id раздела или диска для дальнейшей загрузки? И во-вторых, а не окажется ли потом, что вроде бы всё работает, а часть данных используется со старого диска? Типа того же раздела восстановления?

Comment: В винде есть встроенная утилита для сохранения образа диска, потом он просто разворачивается на другой диск (потребуется загрузная флешка или сидюк, предлагают создать после сохранения образа).

Comment: @Эникейщик, как называется? И разве она для системного диска? Я думал, это бэкапная штуковина. И вопрос про работоспособность переноса образа всё ещё имеется.

Comment: где-то там в настройках в разделе "Бэкап и восстановление". Я обычно просто ввожу system image и там уже видно. Я уже раза три так систему переносил, только потом активировать просит. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-10/84fa6683-e3ac-4e93-9139-368af9267869 Но оно делает образ на третий диск, с которого потом восстановление на второй. У меня дисков несколько, поэтому без проблем. Образ сделал, старый системный диск вынул, новый воткнул, образ развернул.

Comment: Именно это я и пытаюсь сказать. Все идентификаторы внутри разделов не трогаются, т.е. копируются как есть 1в1. На счёт "используются данные старого диска" - ну если ты не будешь затирать старый или не отключишь его - винда вполне может его заюзать - это не будет зависеть от метода и проги по копированию.

Comment: @donRumata, я понимаю, что разделы копируются как есть. Но я не понимаю, это решает мою задачу или нет... Я ж не бэкап хочу сделать, а перенос.

Comment: А теперь читаем мой первый пост и ищем там название режима, который я упомянул.

Answer (score 0):

Перенёс самсунговской утилитой [Data Migration](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/). Умеет переносить только на самсунговские ssd и имеет ещё пачку ограничений.

Впрочем, получилось подозрительно (я не уверен, были ли ошибки до переноса или появились после):

[image: скриншот sfc]

И ещё разделы на новом диске в другом порядке:

[image: скриншот разделов]

После исправления снова словил bsod при обновлении. Но первый bsod появился до переноса, а не после... Вообще, после исправления ошибок и обновления больше не падала.

Answer (score 0):

сменить букву диска можно через MiniTool Partition Wizard или через управление дисками,а почему 93 и 46 гигов места остались болтаться пустыми? надо задействовать

Comment: Это overprovisioning, рекомендуемый самсунгом. Около 10% места на диске не распределено.

Comment: Кстати, ответ больше на комментарий похож. И зачем вообще менять букву диска?

Comment: не внимательно прочитал "И ещё разделы на новом диске в другом порядке:", решил проблема с буквами разделов.
 
MiniTool Partition Wizard помогает с миграцией, я клонировал Acronis True Image и AOMEI Backupper, работать с перераспределением и сменой размеров разделов привык через gparted, есть на любом загрузочном дистре linux